# Lightning toast message is not working in classic

Tags: toast, lighting-out

I have created a lighting component and used it in a visualforce page by using lighting out. Is there any way to display the toast message?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Salesforce docs:

> `e.force:showToast` event is handled by the one.app container. It’s
> supported in Lightning Experience, Salesforce app, and Lightning
> communities.

It doesn't say anything about classic or VF, so my best guess is
You have to manually implement toast using [SLDS](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/toast/).

Src: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:showToast

Comment: My usual tactics are to just try to fire a default toast, and if that fails, an alert. However, you're absolutely correct, one could easily build a custom toast component to use in other places.